# fusing IMU and GPS,make rosbag manually

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to fusing IMU and GPS data to smooth the GPS data,and I followed the question https://answers.ros.org/question/200071/how-to-fuse-imu-gps-using-robot_localization/ .
I write my launch file and parameter.yaml .And I make my rosbag file,but I do not know
how to set the imu data frame id and gps data frame id.

And the rqt_graph is as follows :https://imgur.com/a/wNaLG

############################################

```
<launch>

  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find robot_localization)/params/ekf_imu_gps.yaml" />


  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_se_map" clear_params="true">
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_map"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform" clear_params="true">
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_map"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

##################################################

```
ekf_se_map:
  frequency: 30
  sensor_timeout: 0.1
  two_d_mode: false
  transform_time_offset: 0.0
  transform_timeout: 0.0
  print_diagnostics: true
  debug: false

  map_frame: map
  odom_frame: odom
  base_link_frame: base_link
  world_frame: map

  # odom0: odometry/gps
  odom0: odometry/gps
  odom0_config: [true, true, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]
  odom0_queue_size: 10
  odom0_nodelay: true
  odom0_differential: false
  odom0_relative: false

  imu0: imu/data
  imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                false, false, false,
                false, false, false,
                true,  true,  true,
                true,  true,  true]
  imu0_nodelay: false
  imu0_differential: false
  imu0_relative: false
  imu0_queue_size: 10
  imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

  use_control: false

  process_noise_covariance: 
                            [1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.5,   0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.5,   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.1,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3]

  initial_estimate_covariance: 
                               [1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,   0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1.0,   0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1.0,   0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1.0,  0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1.0,  0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1.0]



navsat_transform:
  frequency: 30
  delay: 0
  magnetic_declination_radians: 0.05288347 # For lat/long 55.944831, -3.186998
  yaw_offset: 1.570796327  # IMU reads 0 facing magnetic north, not east
  zero_altitude: true
  broadcast_utm_transform: true
  publish_filtered_gps: true
  use_odometry_yaw: false
  wait_for_datum: false
```

The bag file script is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import rospy
import rosbag
import numpy as np
from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu
from sensor_msgs.msg import NavSatFix
def make_imu_data(a,b,t,n):
    a=np.array(a)
    b=np.array(b)
    message1=Imu()
    message1.header.seq=n
    message1.header.stamp.secs=float(t.split(".")[0])
    message1.header.stamp.nsecs=float(t.split(".")[1])*1e3
    **message1.header.frame_id='odom'**
    message1.orientation.x=0
    message1.orientation.y=0
    message1.orientation.z=0
    message1.orientation.w=0
    message1.orientation_covariance=np.array([-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1])
    message1.linear_acceleration.x=float(a[0])
    message1.linear_acceleration.y=float(a[1])
    message1.linear_acceleration.z=float(a[2])
    message1.linear_acceleration_covariance=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
    message1.angular_velocity.x=float(b[0])
    message1.angular_velocity.y=float(b[1])
    message1.angular_velocity.z=float(b[2])
    message1.angular_velocity_covariance=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
    return message1

def make_gps_data(latitude,longitude,t,i):
    message2=NavSatFix()
    message2.header.seq=i
    message2.header.stamp.secs=float(t.split(".")[0])
    message2.header.stamp.nsecs=float(t.split(".")[1])*1e3
    message2.header.frame_id='/gps' 
    message2.status.status=1
    message2.status.service=1
    message2.longitude=float(longitude)
    message2.latitude=float(latitude)
    message2.altitude=np.NAN
    message2.position_covariance=np.array([0.64, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.64, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.56])
    message2.position_covariance_type=0
    return message2
#
#
# with rosbag.Bag('test.bag', 'w') as bag:
#     pass
imufile='/home/xiangchen2011/Desktop/imu.txt'
gpsfile='/home/xiangchen2011/Desktop/gps.txt'
with open(gpsfile) as dataset:
    row_numer=1
    with rosbag.Bag('test.bag', 'w') as bag:
        for line in dataset.readlines():
            gps_data=line.split()
            # print imu_data,row_numer
            row_numer=row_numer+1
            msg=make_gps_data(gps_data[2],gps_data[1],gps_data[0],row_numer)
            # print msg.header.stamp
            bag.write('/gps/fix',msg,msg.header.stamp)

with open(imufile) as dataset:
    row_numer=1
    with rosbag.Bag('test.bag', 'a') as bag:
        for line in dataset.readlines():
            imu_data=line.split()
            # print imu_data,row_numer
            row_numer=row_numer+1
            msg=make_imu_data(imu_data[1:4],imu_data[4:7],imu_data[0],row_numer)
            # print msg.angular_velocity
            bag.write('/imu/data',msg,msg.header.stamp)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283419/fusing-imu-and-gps,make-rosbag-manually/) by [omoyouo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33819/omoyouo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2018-02-23**:
Please clarify, is the question on how to set the frame_id in the messages of the bag file?

**Comment by [omoyouo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33819/omoyouo/) on 2018-02-24**:
Yes,you can say that

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2018-02-25**:
How about using the [rosbag API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook) to set the frame_id. Start with the 1.1 example and set msg.header.frame_id instead of msg.header.stamp

**Comment by [omoyouo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33819/omoyouo/) on 2018-02-25**:
Yes,you can see it from the  bag file script (at the last).I set the imu message frame id to 'odom' and the gps message to 'gps'

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2018-02-25**:
Have missed the script, whats your problem with it?

**Comment by [omoyouo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33819/omoyouo/) on 2018-02-25**:
The problem is that it dose not work.I set up these two frame_id  casually,I wonder if this is the reason that  the project did not work.If so ,what should I set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just want to fuse a GPS + IMU to a smooth `tf` maybe geodetic_utils is an alternative solution. The

https://github.com/ethz-asl/geodetic_utils/blob/master/src/gps_to_pose_conversion_node.cpp

listens to both for fusing them an broadcasting `tf`

See:

https://github.com/ethz-asl/geodetic_utils

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2018-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Femer](https://answers.ros.org/users/26134/femer/) on 2018-02-25**:
I think "fusing" is rather a misleading word in this context. geodetic_utils can merge together an IMU message and a GPS message but for sure it does not "fuse" IMU measurements to smooth out GPS coordinates.

**Comment by [omoyouo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33819/omoyouo/) on 2018-02-25**:
I just want to use the IMU data (about 1Khz) to smooth the GPS data (1Hz),so I can use the filtered gps results (may be 1Hz) as the groundtruth  in a way.